# Using beep(freq,duration) Repeatedly

Tags: vb.net, beep

I am trying to create a piano that will play the correct note by either pressing the assigned key or clicking the buttons.

It works so far using the `beep(freq, duration)` function, but that command has a limitation of one note at a time. So if I run through all the notes, it will lag behind until it has played every note at the set duration.

I want to play the note only as long as the button is pressed or the key is pushed down, and also have the ability to play more than one note at a time. I know of the hardware limitations of most keyboards, but I would at least like to be able to press 3 keys at once, and have all three notes generate and play at the same time, not back to back after it has been through its set duration.

The code I have been using:

```
Beep(GlobalVariables.frqD, intDuration)
```

with Beep declared as:

```
Private Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal soundFrequency As Int32, ByVal soundDuration As Int32) As Int32
```

Comment: Is it actually possible to `Beep` at the same time? e.g. try `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub() Beep(xxx, 5))` on three lines with three different frequencies. If you actually get the chord then what you want should be possible.

Comment: I tried doing that, replacing the standard `Beep` function that I had set for the 'C' key to three sets of that code, stacked, with the correct frequencies set for a chord, and recieved no sound.

Answer (score 0):

Playing as long as the key is pressed should be easy.

```
while(keypressed)
{
    beep(freq,millisecond);
}
```

the frequency of the really short beeps should make it sound like a single note(temporal frequency, not auditory frequency, aha).

The thing about the beep method though, is last I checked it used the speaker on the motherboard, not your actual speakers. I could be wrong, but it seems as though you can't get more than one tone at a time. Try something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32892/DirectSound-Beep-Implementation), or just google yourself a proper audio playing library. That should be possible to create chords with.

Comment: It is able to output to my headphones when they are plugged in, so I assume they output to more than just the motherboard. I will look into the link you mentioned. Are there any good audio libraries for VB.net?

Comment: Oh, I could be wrong then. But if you can't play three notes simultaneously like Wayne said, then it seems probably that it can't be done with that function. Look around for VB.net audio libries and you'll find a bunch that will work.

Comment: I found several that will play audio if a variety of formats, but not one that will generate a sine/cos wave? Those were all in C#

Comment: Are you cool with just playing midi notes? Is that what you're trying to do? Just beeps?

Comment: I looked into that, and it seems to call several things that aren't defined, and I don't know where to start to define them.

Comment: What do yo9u mean by undefined? Like you haven't added the requisite .dll files to your project?